# Sharing a variable between coffee files in Meteor

Tags: variables, coffeescript, meteor

I want to share a variable between coffeescript files in my Meteor app without polluting the global namespace using "@".

Is there a way to share variables only between coffeescript files?

Comment: I was just shown that ' share. ' before a variable will make it accessible to the other coffeescript files in the package source code. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to do this. When you declare the variable, add "share." in front of it. So if I wanted to declare variable "info", I would write:

share.info

Then this variable will be shared amongst all of your coffeescript files.

Comment: Thanks! Someone just showed it to me in the coffeescript package source code.

Comment: It is also available to JavaScript files via the global `__coffeescriptShare` object.

Comment: @yimmy what would be the difference with @ and share? i think its the same. You have to put all of your global variable with share.

Comment: @ChrisIan Hi, I haven't gone back to this in a while, but from what I remember, it is only shared within your coffeescript files (I haven't tested what MasterAM said), so people can't call these variables from outside, such as their browser console. It is not the same as @

Answer (score 0):

CoffeeScript is just a more perl like syntax for javascript and is converted to javascript before execution in the browser.

As a result there is no way to limit the variable's reach specifically within the coffeescript files.